# issue while deleting row in database by php

Tags: php, database, delete-row

Hello I have a table in my database called files and I want to delete a row by its id but whenever I run the code I get the response "Successfully Deleted" but it does not delete the row.
This is my code.
I would appreciate any help.

```
<?php

require "conn.php";

$id = $_POST["id"];

if($conn){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE id LIKE '$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($query)>0) {
    $sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM files WHERE id LIKE '$id'";
    echo "Successfully Deleted";
} else {
    echo "Failed to delete";
}

} else {
    echo "Connection Error";
}

?>
```

I guess the issue is because id in database is Int but I'm passing Strings to it so how should I solve this problem?

Comment: You haven't executed the DELETE-query... You have only definde the query string without the query call. Note that you should consider using prepared statements

Comment: Also note that it's better to use a direct comparison (`=`) instead of using `LIKE`, since you're looking for exact matches. They behave the same in this case, but direct comparison is quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you assign

```php
$sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM files WHERE id LIKE '$id'";
```

you need to

```php
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlDelete))
{
 echo "Successfully Deleted";
}
```

in order to *execute* the delete query. BTW the `select` statement is redundant.

**Please note that your code is very unsafe and SQLi prone. Use prepared statements instead of text substitution.**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM files WHERE id = ".$id;
 mysqli_query($conn,$sqlDelete );
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation of what was changed, so that OP and any future readers can easily understand where the error was and learn something.

Comment: Warning! Just like the OP's original code, this is wide open for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks. _Never_ add parameters to the query like this. Use prepared statements with bound parameters instead.

Comment: Magnus thanks. as I'm new to php I had no idea about that and this link helped me a lot.